# Tighten 'rubber band' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, math, mobile

So I'm wondering if anyone has any insight as to how I can create a tightening rubber band effect as the user pulls down. I was using an exponential equation that didn't work very well. I'd post it if I still had it but it was something along the lines of

```
Math.pow(0.98, moveY - startY);
```

The numbers that run through the equation range from 1 - 600. Though it worked, it would reverse direction if pulled too far. So I'm sure I'm just drawing a blank from sleep deprivation, but if anyone could lend a hand? I checked on [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/), but I found that the rubber band is just a static ratio that never 'tightens'.
Thanks

Comment: Tightening would imply an increase in the tension, whereas you have no means to convey force feedback to the user.

Comment: What is your formula supposed to calculate anyway?

Comment: Basically it's just the effect that you get on the iphone when you overscroll on a webpage. You pull down and it feels like the scrolling is 'tightening'.